# URL rule for dynamic suffix in Yii2

Tags: regex, yii, url-rewriting, yii2

I want to receive a parameter from URL with extension in that.
Here is my controller:

```
public function actionIndex($directory=null,$filename=null)
    {

     echo $directory.$filename;exit;
    }
```

Here is my URL rule:

```
 '<directory:\w+>/<filename:\w+>' => 'file/index',
```

it works like that:

```
localhost/uploads/abc
```

But it shows 404 when I do this:

```
localhost/uploads/abc.pdf
```

Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Comment: Did you check that you don't have static file processing by web server enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that with following regex:

```
  '<directory:\w+>/<filename:\w+[.]\w+>' => 'file/index'
```